# How can I use autoencoders for noise detection and removal

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, autoencoder

How can I use autoencoders for noise detection and removal in a dataset with only 2 features and no labels? How should my architecture be like, such as 2 1 1 1 2 or any other? And does the output of autuencoders give the noise removed data?

Comment: Take a look at this [Keras tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/vision/autoencoder/).